# PDF doesn't load in a object tag

Tags: html, pdf

The pdf path it's ok, but the browser doesn't load the PDF in the object tag.

Response Header:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=1.pdf
Content-Length:234790
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Tue, 28 Oct 2014 14:26:16 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 09 Jul 2014 14:00:55 GMT
Server:nginx/0.7.67
Set-Cookie:sessionid=1c64bc0b9ab545d9f7568c09a8ed6fe3; httponly; Path=/
```

Object code:

```
<object data="http://example.com/protected/documents/7" type="application/pdf">
    <p>File:  
        <a href="/protected/documents/7" target="_blank" class="turquesa"> 
           /protected/documents/7
        </a>
    </p>
</object>
```

If I click in the fallback link I download the PDF, so the server is working right.

So... any idea?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the browser you are using has no native (or plug-in) support for displaying PDFs. Trying to view a PDF in a small object window is a horrible UI anyway. Downloads are much nicer.

Comment: Client requiriments!

And I use the last google chrome

Comment: It's usually a good idea to tell a client when they are being an idiot (although phrased more diplomatically).

Comment: LOL I would try, but that's not the problem now ;-)

Comment: Since they are asking you to do something I suspect may be impossible, it kinda is your problem ;)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `Content-Disposition` header. "attachment" tells the browser to download the file rather than displaying it inline. If you are able to change the response so that it reads "inline" instead that will resolve the problem.